# How to reduce / remove BANDWIDTH_IN lines from kernel info.log file?

Tags: kernel, logs

First some information.

```
Linux 4.4.36-desktop-2.mga5 #1 SMP Tue Dec 6 16:56:06 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is a media server connected to the network via wifi. For some reason, this machine's `/var/log/kernel/info.log` is gathering a whole lot of network traffic information.

```
Dec 31 01:50:21 adamsmdk kernel: [89569.691542] BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=7c:c3:a1:b5:d4:41:00:19:d1:71:dd:e7:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.105 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35757 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=791 DPT=2049 WINDOW=371 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Dec 31 01:50:21 adamsmdk kernel: [89569.691790] BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=7c:c3:a1:b5:d4:41:00:19:d1:71:dd:e7:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.105 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=180 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35758 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=791 DPT=2049 WINDOW=371 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Dec 31 01:50:21 adamsmdk kernel: [89569.732233] BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=7c:c3:a1:b5:d4:41:00:19:d1:71:dd:e7:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.105 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35759 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=791 DPT=2049 WINDOW=371 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Dec 31 01:50:21 adamsmdk kernel: [89569.777177] BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=7c:c3:a1:b5:d4:41:40:16:7e:22:a1:ca:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.106 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=52 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=48506 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=50784 DPT=xxxxx WINDOW=1939 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Dec 31 01:50:21 adamsmdk kernel: [89569.841672] BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=7c:c3:a1:b5:d4:41:40:16:7e:22:a1:ca:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.106 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=52 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=48507 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=50784 DPT=xxxxx WINDOW=1939 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Dec 31 01:50:21 adamsmdk kernel: [89569.936860] BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=7c:c3:a1:b5:d4:41:40:16:7e:22:a1:ca:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.106 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=52 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=48508 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=50784 DPT=xxxxx WINDOW=1939 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Dec 31 01:50:21 adamsmdk kernel: [89569.974945] BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=7c:c3:a1:b5:d4:41:40:16:7e:22:a1:ca:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.106 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=88 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=21970 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=49168 DPT=xxxxx WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Dec 31 01:50:21 adamsmdk kernel: [89569.977561] BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=7c:c3:a1:b5:d4:41:40:16:7e:22:a1:ca:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.106 DST=192.168.1.100 LEN=5:</code>
```

I can see that this traffic is legitimate and generated on my network. I'd like for the logging to stop, but I have no idea what is actually generating that kernel info message much less how to stop it.

Can anybody suggest a kernel log setting or troubleshooting to be done here?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that **BANDWIDTH_IN** message, so I think is hardware-specific.
Try to look into your Wi-Fi kernel module for options, likely *debug* options:

1. search for the implicated module name
2. use `modinfo` to get available parameters

Comment: Those seemed like good ideas. I tracked down the driver for the Atheros-based wifi card. I can't tell from the information provided by modinfo whether debug is setup correctly or not.

Comment: Tried to respond but Users without post commenting privilege can't edit auto-generated comments.

Comment: Take a look here, too: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#Atheros